# Import data from MS Access 2003 db using MS Jet OLEDB 4 drivers into Excel 2003 gives ISAM error

Tags: excel, excel-2003, ms-access-2003, vba

I am trying to run query stored in an MS Access 2003 database through Excel 2003. The connections string is as follows:

```
 flLoc=thisworkbook.path
 stDB= floc & "\list.mdb"
 stConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & stDB & ";"
```

The db is currently stored in a network folder. I am able to connect to the Access db using the above connection string from my machine, however when one of my colleagues opens the file and tries to click the button that has the code and connection string associated with the button, he gets an "could not find installable ISAM". Both machines are using Access 2003 and Excel 2003 version.

Any suggestions how to make this work?

Please note that editing the registry is not an option as users do not have admin rights and file is going to be used by multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this KB from Microsoft:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805

As to modifying the registry, this looks like an individual machine error and has to be fixed and may require and admin to fix the registration on the DLL.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I went through it and that's why I mentioned reged is not an option that i can use. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the other person was using Access 2002 version on his machine to view the reports. The reports link to SharePoint lists and Access 2002 does not offer connectivity to Sharepoint as such.